# How to launch my web application on startup? OpenBSD

Tags: openbsd

I just migrated a web application from NodeJS to Go, and I am having troubles getting it to run on startup. Previously using my Node app, I would use [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to handle starting the app. However I cannot find a good way to do this with Go.

I have looked into making my own service with `rc.d` but I can't really find anything that helpful. Is there an easy way to do this? I can compile the source code to binary if need be.

At the moment I have it just running in a TTY, but I would really like it to be a daemon.

**Edit:** Just to clarify, I am using NGiNX to reverse proxy the Go app.

Comment: The `nginx` package is installed with its own `/etc/rc.d/nginx` file. What is the issue with enabling and starting this using `rcctl enable nginx; rcctl start nginx` as root?

Comment: @they I already have NGiNX configured like that. However, the go application needs to be run on startup as well so NGiNX can reverse proxy it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use the `rc.d` infrastructure (you should), you can just add whatever is appropriate to `/etc/rc.local` BUT remember that everything there is run as `root`, so you'll probably want to use `su` to run your application as another user (and while you're at it, check if you want to run it `chroot`ed somewhere).

If you want to go the `rc.d` way, you might want to start by skimming throug the man pages for `rc.d` and `rc.subr`, and the template at `/usr/ports/infrastructure/templates/rc.template` might also be a big help.  Yet another option is to find an already ported Go web application, install it and see how it is run.  For instance gitea is installed as a compiled binary and then has a very simple `/etc/rc.d/gitea` script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
# $OpenBSD: gitea.rc,v 1.6 2021/01/17 21:07:41 pvk Exp $

daemon="/usr/local/sbin/gitea"
daemon_user="_gitea"

. /etc/rc.d/rc.subr

rc_bg=YES
rc_reload=NO

rc_cmd $1
```

Comment: Thanks for this, `rc.d` doesn't seem too tough when you put it like this!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an OpenBSD guy, but don't you just need to make sure that httpd starts at boot?

Comment: That would work if I was serving plain html, but I am running a reverse proxy with NGiNX.